# How to define a new class that inherits from Delegate

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

is there anyway to do something similar to what ive got bellow.

What im trying to do is to invoke a list of delegates at a specific point in time and keep track of them, and for the sake of keeping code clean, keep the delegates to be invoked in a list of some sort.

```
public interface IServiceStatusDelegate
{
    object DynamicInvoke(object[] args)
}

public class ServiceStatusDelegate
   : Delegate, IServiceStatusDelegate
{
}

public class MyServiceStatusCheckedDelegate
   : ServiceStatusDelgate
{
}

public class MyServiceStatusChangedDelegate
   : ServiceStatusDelgate
{
}
public class MyClass
{
    public ServiceStatusDelgate[] listOfDelegatesToInvoke;

    public void InvokeRequiredDelegates()
    {
        foreach(ServiceStatusDelegate delegateToInvoke in this.listOfDelegatesToInvoke)
            delegateToInvoke.DynamicInvoke(new object[]{this, DateTime.Now});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* a list of delegates... any delegate you create in c# is going to be multicast, so all you need is *any* delegate, and you can combine them with `+`. Just invoke it and all targets will be reached. For example:

```
Action target = null;
...
target += Method1;
...
target += Method2;
...
if(target != null) target(); // calls Method1 and Method2
```

This *could* (although it isn't necessary for it to stand) be implemented via an `event` which will make the convention very obvious the caller.